# Naming of input elements in a dynamically created form

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to Javascript, so sorry if I don't use the correct terminology.

I have a form that can dynamically grow. In other words I have buttons that will add labels and input fields to  whenever the user clicks it.

At the end of the form, I'd like to have some "done" button that runs another JavaScript function.

However I notice that all of the input fields have the same id (since the function makes the id the same each time).

What is the correct way to access these variables???

Below is the function to dynamically create the fields.
I havent written the function to use the form yet.

```
function buildDefaultFields(){
    // Define container
    var chargeItem_container = document.getElementById("chargeItem_container");
    // INPUT Start Date
    chargeItem_container.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Start Date: '));
    var startDate = document.createElement("input");
    startDate.type = 'date';
    startDate.name = 'startDate';
    startDate.id = 'startDate';
    chargeItem_container.appendChild(startDate);
    chargeItem_container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dynamically add the elements such that each element gets a new id. You could use a simple counter to append to your id names.

For example, if you keep a global `var count = 0`, then your first id could be `'startDate-' + count` which will be `startDate-0`, then perform an increment on `count`, so that the next time you add an element, it will get the id `'startDate-' + count` = `startDate-1`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That should work fine! thanks, I was just wondering if this was the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an id if its not going to uniquely identify a single element, instead use a class

```
startDate.className = 'startDate';
```

then use getElementsByClassName to retrieve them

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName ('startDate');// then loop through the elements

Comment: Will the be ordered in any particular way?

Comment: @kamula I'm guessing the elements in the returned collection are in source order, but I can't say for sure.